# Como associar uma ImageView a uma Classe?

Tags: java, android

Apesar de ser algo genérico, para tentar esclarecer a minha dúvida, irei dar um exemplo.

Por exemplo, tenho um `HashMap<Integer, Piece>` com tamanho 64, em que Integer seria posição e Piece, classe para uma peça de tabuleiro. E tenho um layout com 64 `ImageView`(Quadrado 8x8), querendo relacionar isto, ou seja cada `ImageView` é uma `Piece` e a sua posição um `Integer`? 
Como se faz esta associação entre Views e classes?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o método setTag(Object) da view para guardar nela o seu map, por exemplo. Dá uma lida na  [documentaço da classe View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)